# rspec-sidekiq: How to test "within_sidekiq_retries_exhausted_block" with another class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sidekiq, rspec-sidekiq

I am using gem "rspec-sidekiq" to test "sidekiq_retries_exhausted".

This is my worker:

```
class PostListingsWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :retry => 0

  sidekiq_retries_exhausted do |msg|
    NotifyMailer.warn_email(msg).deliver_now
  end

  def perform(params, fetch_time)
  ....
  end
end
```

This is an example from "rspec-sidekiq" github:

```
sidekiq_retries_exhausted do |msg|
  bar('hello')
end
# test with...
FooClass.within_sidekiq_retries_exhausted_block {
  expect(FooClass).to receive(:bar).with('hello')
}
```

I think it should input methods in "sidekiq_retries_exhausted" block as symbol into test.
I followed this way, but it doesn't work.

Here is my test.Look at the receive() method.:

```
it 'should send email when retries exhausted' do
    msg = {error_message: 'Wrong', args: [{id: 1}]}.to_json
    PostListingsWorker.within_sidekiq_retries_exhausted_block(msg) {
      expect(PostListingsWorker).to receive(:"NotifyMailer.warn_email().deliver_now").with(msg)
    }
 end
```

Here is my log:

```
Failure/Error: expect(PostListingsWorker).to > >
receive(:"NotifyMailer.warn_email().deliver_now").with(:msg)
PostListingsWorker does not implement: NotifyMailer.warn_email().deliver_now
```

So，is there any way to test a method belong to another class during "sidekiq_retries_exhausted"?
Maybe find some way to send method as symblo?

Answer (score 3):

You're close. However, you can simply write your expectation against the `NotifyMailer` like this:

```
email = double('email')
msg = double('msg')

PostListingsWorker.within_sidekiq_retries_exhausted_block(msg) {
  expect(NotifyMailer).to receive(:warn_email).with(msg).and_return(email)
  expect(email).to receive(:deliver_now)
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way to test this?